# how to deal with object when while fetching data it is initially null and then it gets filled with data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to extract some information from the props this way.

```
let roleType=this.props.user.data.permissions.map((val)=>{

            console.log(val);
});
```

In the initial stage when the component is getting rendered data has nothing inside it so I get an error that it can't map over which is true.
How do I deal with these cases. If I console log the above props I see that data is initially empty and then it gets filled.  However, the web app crashes because of this?

Comment: depends on how `data` is populated .. at a guess, it's asynchronous behaviour that you don't know how to deal with - but you haven't shown nearly enough code to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid cases when you try to deal with such scenarios, you either intialize the data in the format you expect it to be or you provide conditional checks to it while using

```
let roleType=this.props.user && this.props.user.data && this.props.user.data.permissions && this.props.user.data.permissions.map((val)=>{
        console.log(val);
});
```

or initialise it like

```
state = {
    user: {
         data: {
             permissions: []
         }
    }
}
```

What other thing that you can do to avoid unexpected undefined scenarios is to use PropType validation

```
Component.propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.shape({
         data: PropTypes.shape({
             permissions: PropTypes.Array
         })
    })
}
```

One other improvement that you can do over the first method is to write a function that checks for nested data

```
function checkNested(obj, accessor) {
  var args = accessor.split('.')

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
let roleType= checkNested(this.props.user, 'data.permissions') && this.props.user.data.permissions.map((val)=>{
        console.log(val);
});
```

> P.S. You can also improve the above method to take into consideration
>   the array index

Answer (score 0):

Simply check to see if the object has the required attributes you're looking for before mapping through it. If it doesn't use an empty array.

```
let roleType = this.props.user.data ? this.props.user.data.permissions.map((val) => {
  console.log(val);
}) : [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have to make an API call to get the data, so add that code for fetching the data in `componentDidmount` once the response came, set the data response in the `state`. So that component will render again with updated data.

> Also, put a condition on the rendering section where going to use the state so that it won't be trying to access any property of a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Like other people stated, the question doesn't really tell how you receive the data. My answer is based on you getting the data on load time. This answer doesn't work if you get the data externally or through an async call.

You can wait for the DOM Content to be fully loaded before running the code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let roleType=this.props.user.data.permissions.map((val)=>{
        console.log(val);
    });
}, false);
```

Another way to do this is by waiting for the page to be fully loaded. This includes images and styling.

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
    let roleType=this.props.user.data.permissions.map((val)=>{
        console.log(val);
    });
}
```

The first one is quicker in running, but you might be better of if you need the images to be loaded before running the code.

Finally it could also be a problem with the order of your code and simply placing your code lower might also fix the problem.